# How to draw wxProgressDialog in wxGridcell in c++ using wxwidgets 2.8.10?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

How to set wxProgressDialog in 2nd column of wxGrid cells .based on grid 1st column values i want to change the corresponding Progress dialog status in 2nd column?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'd suggest that you catch the "on change" event from the first column and then change the corresponding progess bar. Also the wxGrid is not the "right" Control to do this, you should consider using "wxDataViewCtrl" or some of it's derivates. It would also be nice to have some code to work with, because I don't think somebody is going to do all of it for you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `wxProgressDialog` is a dialog, i.e. a top level window, so it can't be embedded into a cell, what you are looking for is called [wxGauge](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_gauge.html) in wxWidgets API.

Second, there is no way to draw a native `wxGauge`, unfortunately. The simplest thing you may do is to just draw a solid rectangle in a custom [wxGridCellRendererer](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_grid_cell_renderer.html).

Finally, the simplest way to do what you want would be to use [wxDataViewCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_data_view_ctrl.html) instead of `wxGrid` as it supports "progress" cells out of the box and the sample shows how to use them.